# Working with Fingerprint Detection from an image in android

Tags: android, opencv, fingerprinting

I intend to work on a project, where I have to detect fingerprint from an image captured by android's camera.

I have no prior knowledge on fingerprint processing. Is there any open source library in android to accomplish the task? If not, then from which point can I have to start to gain adequate knowledge about fingerprint detection and processing?

I have not worked with image processing before. So there is so much to cover up, i can do that. But I want to know the exact starting point so that I don't have to circle around ...

Any links, papers or books related on this topic will be very convenient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @SALEH. Did you manage to complete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How will the phone camera take an image like [this](http://www.idfpr.com/DPR/images/fingerprint.gif)? Fingerprints are acquired using specialized sensors.

If you're talking about getting fingerprint data from a normal photograph of a finger, I doubt you'll be able to distinguish between fingerprints accurately.